# Chi-square test for more than 2x2 tables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

There are there groups (colA, colB, colC) representing three different measurement methods. The question is whether there is a difference between the three methods. To decide the question we perform experiments and measure the same thing with each method. The output of each method is a label not a value on a numeric scale. In addition, we do not have a control group so we do not know which method's output is the right one in the experiment. I solved the question in the way below  but I became uncertain whether it is a correct solution. I might have oversimplified the problem. Consequently, the chi-square approach used tests something else not what we want.

```
Data:
            colA,    colB,    colC
experiment1 label1,  label1,  label2
experiment2 label3,  label1,  label3
experiment3 label4,  label4,  label2
experiment4 label5,  label4,  label5
...
```

- My first approach, probably oversimplified:

As we do not know which label is correct and which not, we regard at first all the outputs of method A correct and compare them to the other two columns and count the same labels in the same experiments in the other columns, then we regard all the outputs of method B correct and then method C. So we get the label count below:

```
I. colA regarded as correct
colA(4) colB(2) colC(2)

II. colB regarded as correct
colA(2), colB(4), colC(0)

III. colC regarded as correct
colA(2), colB(0), colC(4)
```

Then we compute a **chi-square test for each**, here II. and III. are the same. (There are more than 5 expected values in each column it is just the example to highlight the problem.) This way we get three p values for each test, from which we select the highest one to be on the safe side and decide whether the deviations between columns are likely to be caused by chance only.

- My second approach would probably be:

The data same data transformed in a different format:

```
                        label1, label2, label3, label4, label5
methodA (earlier colA)       1,      0,      1,      1,      1,
methodB (earlier colB)       2,      0,      0,      2,      0,
methodC (earlier colC)       0,      2,      1,      0,      1,
```

Here the expected values for each label would be greater than 5 with the real data. However, we do not want to test whether the distribution among the labels are caused by chance only but whether there is a difference between the methodA, methodB and methodC. **Can Chi-Square be used here?** What other tests would you propose to use to see whether there is a difference between the three methods?

**What would be your solution?** Thank you also in advance for any comments.